# How to create partition in Ubuntu using Gparted?

Tags: partitioning

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and now I want to create a partition in my hard drive.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHXaj.png)
But I have only one partition and I found in a video that one cannot create partition which is being used. I am unable to create partition. What should I do?

Comment: I am unable to resize.

Comment: You can't resize a partition that is being used. Boot a USB Ubuntu stick, Try Ubuntu (live session). Run Gparted from there.

Comment: Is there any videos available online?